# Prohibir subida de carpetas en un input de HTML

Tags: html

estoy intentando que no suceda esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece dropZone, pero no lo es, es un input type="file" quiero hacer que no te deje subir carpetas.
Grax

Comment: Bienvenido!, Te recomiendo  dar una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), para conocer como funciona el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla. Es importante que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para poder mejorar tu pregunta y así sea bien recibida. Falta el código y lo que has probado.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, pero el código no lo considero de relevancia ya que como he dicho es un simple input. Lo adjunto por si puede aclarar a alguien

Comment: Esto lleva mucho mas que un input, hay mucha mas lógica, sin ello poco podemos hacer.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.